# How to check what is starting Finder?

Tags: finder, startup

I have Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard, and installed the Path Finder file manager for replacing the builtin Finder.

Because of that, I have Path Finder setup so that the original Finder is quit during startup. However, during system use sometimes Finder would seem to spontaneously start. Is there a way to check what I did to trip it, or what application, is making Finder start?

Thanks.

Comment: It might be easier to watch and see what finder folder gets opened (does a window open or is is just added to the dock with no windows?) My hunch is a certain file type is getting passed to the open command which things Finder is the best app to open - you can then change the database to set these to be PathFinder on a case by case basis,

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be in the code of some applications.

> What applications support Path Finder?
>
> The vast majority of applications support Path Finder with absolutely no compatibility >problems, but some applications go one step further and had special integration built >in.
>
> A small list of examples include:
>
> A-Dock
> Quicksilver
> Butler
> Name Mangler
> DragThing
> Default Folder X
> LaunchBar
> Change Desktop
> Some applications do require Apple's Finder to work properly as they are hard-wired >this way. If you would like to see compatibility added for one of your favorite apps, >visit our forum and let us know!

Their forum is located at http://www.cocoatech.com/forum/. See if you can find any applications that you use that are listed there that have issues. Finder is such an integral part of the operating system that replacing it requires applications not to call Finder or for Path Finder to intercept those calls I assume.